# How can I get multiple Javascript setInterval functions to play nicely together on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, setinterval

I have written a few custom animation functions as jQuery plugins using a `setInterval()` for the loop.

The functions seem to work fine by themselves but when I try to include more than one of them in the same page the timings and effects get all messed up and don't render or complete properly!

I have done some scouting around on stackOverflow and google and from what I can gather the problem is that `setInterval` acts as a 'global' method / property of the `window` object and so when I have more than one on the page they end up overwriting each other!

Is this correct? And if so what is the solution? What does jQuery / plugins do to manage their own unique interval functions?

I was wondering if it's possible to set a 'local' `setInterval` as a unique property to each of my plugin objects?

-- OR --

If I have to create a function to manage multiple animation calls from various different plugins / functions to juggle them all with one global `setInterval` call  -- But I have no idea how to do this!

Can anyone help please?

----edit----

```
(function($){
    $.fn.scroller = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            direction: 'left',
            distance: '',
            duration: 2000,
            interval: 2000,
            type: 'linear',
            startPos: '0'
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            parent = $(this).children('.scroller');
            $this = parent.children().first();

//          console.log(parent);
//          console.log($this);

            var o = options;
            var m = '';

            if(o.direction === 'left') m = 'marginLeft';
            if(o.direction === 'right') m = 'marginRight';
            if(o.direction === 'up') m = 'marginTop';
            if(o.direction === 'down') m = 'marginBottom';

//          console.log('Distance: ' + o.distance);
//          console.log('Duration: ' + o.duration);
//          console.log('Type: ' + o.type);
//          console.log('Start Pos: ' + o.startPos);
//          console.log('Interval: ' + o.interval);

            setInterval(function(){
                $this.animate({
                    m : o.distance
                },
                o.duration,
                o.type,
                function() { // OnComplete
                    $this.stop().css(m, o.startPos).appendTo(parent);
                });
            }, o.duration+o.interval);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: why don't you use the internal timing for jquery?

Comment: You can set as many intervals as you like. Any conflicts are likely due to: a) the use of global variables in your interval callbacks, or b) poor performance in the callbacks

Comment: @DanielAWhite because using jQuery to emulate setTimeout is overkill.

Comment: @Raynos - but he is using jquery already.

Comment: @Raynos -- your point may still be valid but just to clarify I'm using setInterval not setTimeout!

Comment: @DanielAWhite but just because you have it on the page doesn't mean you have to use all it's abstractions. If your using jQuery animations sure use the `.delay`. If your doing your own thing don't try to hook into jQuery timing just because you can.

Comment: Another point I should have mentioned is that a recursive function call using a setTimeout that is reset every loop (instead of setInterval) just crashed my browser with a stackoverflow (irony)

Comment: I am having exactly same problem, 2nd setInterval function is overriding the values of first one and hence my internal function runs two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

I think I see the problem. You define $this as a global variable. As such, calls to setInterval will all use the same $this variable. Try `var $this = ...`. Same for `parent`. Also note that in the callback to `$this.animate`, "this" should refer to the dom element that was animated, so you could do $(this) to get a jQuery object for it.

---

I think your problem might be that you loose context with setInterval. The `this` object may not be what you expect it to be. If you expect a variable to be present (because it was defined near where you call setInterval), it probably won't be.

Closures might help you. Try

```
setInterval(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Rather than

```
setInterval(myPreDefinedFunction);
```

Also, try to make sure you are using locally defined variables in your setInterval callback rather than global ones:

```
var myVar = 5;
```

rather than

```
myVar = 5;
```

If you used the second method, you would end up sharing the variable between callbacks.

Comment: Good point about defining the vars properly, thankyou. That's bound to have been causing some issues. Your second point about the jquery DOM object reference doesn't work for me though -- seems to work the way I've got it?!

Comment: have you tried doing `console.log(this);` in the callback? It should be the DOM element of the thing that was animated. Just to clarify, I'm talking about the bit where you use $this in the animate callback just after the comment `//OnComplete`, not on the first part of the setInterval callback ("this" would refer to window there).

Answer (score 0):

it is true that setInterval is global, but each call to setInterval returns a unique ID that you can use to reference it, i.e. for clearInterval().  Each plugin requiring it's own interval should be assigned it's own variable to contain the ID for referencing.  Perhaps it's coming down to how you are managing each of these individually.  Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: I've updated my post with some code. Please go easy on me this is my first attempt at a jquery plugin and I might have missed something glaringly obvious! -- But thanks for your point, I'll look in to it.